# Need assistance with creating a table for java project

Tags: java

So, I'm super new to programming in general. I've been learning Java through a course and one of our projects is to make a program that reads a text file and prints the number of vowels in a little table. (See below example.)

```
A|##
E|##
I|####
O|#
U|
```

I've gotten some work done. For instance getting the total number of vowels. (See below.)

```
String words = input.nextLine();
System.out.println(words);

for (int i=0;i<words.length(); i++)
{
    char car = words.charAt(i);
    if (car =='a'|| car == 'i' || car == 'e' || car=='o' || car == 'u')
    {
        count ++ ;
    }
```

This prints the total number ^

**Output:** 9

After that I worked out a way to print the table. (See below.)

```
//Process for creating the chart (NOT FINAL)
System.out.println(count);
System.out.print("A|");
final int MAX_ROWS = 1 ;
for (int row = 1; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++)
{
    for(int a =5; a >= row; a--)
        System.out.print("#");
}
System.out.println("");
System.out.print("E|");
for (int row = 1; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++)
{
    for(int e =5; e >= row; e--)
        System.out.print("#");
}
System.out.println("");
System.out.print("I|");
for (int row = 1; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++)
{
    for(int ii =5; ii >= row; ii--)
        System.out.print("#");
}
System.out.println("");
System.out.print("O|");
for (int row = 1; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++)
{
    for(int o =5; o >= row; o--)
        System.out.print("#");
}
System.out.println("");
System.out.print("U|");
for (int row = 1; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++)
{
    for(int u =5; u >= row; u--)
        System.out.print("#");
}
```

**Output:**

```
A|#####
E|#####
I|#####
O|#####
U|#####
```

However, I can't figure out how to get the number of each vowel into the table. I've provided the whole thing below to look through for broader context. I apologize for how rough it is, I'm just a bit lost. And I couldn't find anything with my specific table requirement on the Web. I hope one of you can help. Thanks for any answers.

P.S. Since this is a class were I'm trying to learn I want to figure this out on my own. Pointers with explanations would be great. A push in the right direction if you will.

Edit: I want to clarify something that I explained poorly. The `int`s a-u are placeholders and the goal was to use vowels from a text doc. The example from the test doc is "orange tree apple hope". Hope that clarifies.

**Full Code:**

```java
import java.util.Scanner ;
import java.io.File ;

public class VowelCounter
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        File text = new File ("Doc.txt") ;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(text) ;
        //File Doc.txt is scanned and is used 
        int count = 0 ;

        while (input.hasNext())
        {
            String words = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(words);

            for (int i=0;i<words.length(); i++)
            {
                char car = words.charAt(i);
                if (car =='a'|| car == 'i' || car == 'e' || car=='o' || car == 'u')
                {
                    count ++ ;
                }

                //Test Values (NOT FINAL)
                int a = 5 ;
                int e = 5;
                int ii = 5;
                int o = 5;
                int u = 5;
            }

            //Process for creating the chart (NOT FINAL)
            System.out.println(count);
            System.out.print("A|");
            final int MAX_ROWS = 1 ;
            for (int row = 1; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++)
            {
                for(int a =5; a >= row; a--)
                    System.out.print("#");
            }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("E|");
            for (int row = 1; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++)
            {
                for(int e =5; e >= row; e--)
                    System.out.print("#");
            }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("I|");
            for (int row = 1; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++)
            {
                for(int ii =5; ii >= row; ii--)
                    System.out.print("#");
            }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("O|");
            for (int row = 1; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++)
            {
                for(int o =5; o >= row; o--)
                    System.out.print("#");
            }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("U|");
            for (int row = 1; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++)
            {
                for(int u =5; u >= row; u--)
                    System.out.print("#");
            }
        }
        //(ERROR) prints 15 # instead of 4
        // a= 2 e=5 i=0 o=2 u=0 (FOR CHECK)
        // 9 toatl vowels
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a Map<Character, Integer>. Each entry is a vowel, loop through your character by character and increase the integer in the map for each vowel.

Comment: ``` for (int row = 1; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++)``` the for loops are useless

Comment: all you need to do is to remove the for loops and replace your ```row``` in your inner for loops with the number of times each vowl shows up

Comment: [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my comments above I remove the outer for loops and replaced your inner  for loops with occurrences of each vowel shows up

```
 //Test Values (NOT FINAL)
            int aCount = 5 ;
            int eCount = 5;
            int iCount = 5;
            int oCount = 5;
            int uCount = 5;
            //Process for creating the chart (NOT FINAL)
            System.out.println(count);
            System.out.print("A|");
            final int MAX_ROWS = 1 ;
            for(int i =0; i < aCount; i++)
                System.out.print("#");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("E|");
            for(int i =0; i < eCount; i++)
                System.out.print("#");

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("I|");
            for(int i =0; i < iCount; i++)
                System.out.print("#");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("O|");
            for(int i =0; i < oCount; i++)
                System.out.print("#");

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("U|");
            for(int i =0; i < uCount; i++)
                System.out.print("#");

        }
```

and this is what @Just another Java programmer suggested

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Map<Character, Integer> vowelMap  = new HashMap<Character, Integer>() {{
            put('A', 0);
            put('E', 0);
            put('I', 0);
            put('O', 0);
            put('U', 0);
        }};
        String words = "oiwjroiajfdojasoijfalkdfoiejrf";
        for(int i=0;i<words.length();i++){
            char c = Character.toUpperCase(words.charAt(i));
            if(vowelMap.containsKey(c))
                vowelMap.put(c, vowelMap.get(c)+1);;
        }
        vowelMap.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println( k+ "|"+ "#".repeat(v)));
    }
```